# Chain as recipient of a recipient-list-router

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Can I use a router in a chain? Practically the recipient of the router should be a chain.
It should be something like this

```
<int:chain>
    <int:recipient-list-router>
        <int:recipient>
            <int:chain>
                ...
            </int:chain>
        </int:recipient>
       ...
    </int:recipient-list-router>
</int:chain>
```

Comment: I really don't understand why this is downvoted ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; a recipient in that context is a channel not an endpoint.

You would have to declare the (inner) chain as a top level element with an `input-channel` and the recipient would reference that input channel.

```
<int:chain ...>
    <int:recipient-list-router>
        <int:recipient channel="foo" />
        ...
    </int:recipient-list-router>
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="foo">
    ...
</int:chain>
```

Of course, if the `RLR` is the only element in the first chain, as in this example, it is worthless and you might as well declare it as a top level element.

Comment: No; endpoints don't "know" about each other, they are loosely coupled using channels. This allows much more flexibility - like changing channel types, adding interceptors, etc. As a convenience, in the snippet above, it is not necessary to explicitly declare channel `foo` unless you want it to have different behavior to the default (`DirectChannel`).